# Покритиковать скрипт определения простых чисел и преобразовать его

Tags: php

Покритикуйте код

```
<?php
function  isPrime($num) {
    if ($num < 2) {
      echo  "$num is not prime";
        exit();
    }
    for ($i = 2; $i < $num;  $i++) {
        if ($num  %  $i == 0) {
            echo  "$num is not prime";
          exit();
        }
    }
echo  "$num is prime";
}
isPrime(13);
?>
```

Зачем нужен квадратный корень в выражении `for ($i = 2; $i < $num;  $i++)`   если итак всё работает...Но как преобразовать этот код, чтобы был поиск простых чисел в диапазоне от 2 до 13 ?

Comment: _Зачем нужен квадратный корень в выражении, если итак всё работает_ - это значительно сократит количество проверок которые надо будет сделать для определения простоты. Чем большее число надо проверить - тем больше будет заметна разница

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошая функция, только нужно причесать немного, чтобы можно было пользоваться и понимать что за результат получается.

```
function  isPrime($num) {

    $num = (int)$num; //вдруг передали ерунду?

    if ($num < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for ($i = 2; $i < $num;  $i++) {
        if ($num  %  $i == 0) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Прогнал на первых 20 простых числах вида x^4+1, результат весьма достойный.
Число 655360001 проверялось на простоту 59 секунд.

Хотя конечно для майнинга биткоинов такой алгоритм не подойдет. Можно вечно майнить и ничего не намайнить :)

Пример:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i<100) {

   $isPrime = isPrime($i);
   if ( $isPrime === true) {

      echo "$i is prime" . PHP_EOL;
   } else if($isPrime === false) {

      echo "$i is NOT prime, because negative numbers, zero and 1 are not primes" . PHP_EOL;
   } else {

      echo "$i is NOT prime, the divider is {$isPrime}" . PHP_EOL;
   }

   $i++;
}
```

Comment: PHP_EOL можно и не ставить в этот код так как он просто проверяет переданное в функцию число на простоту. А как доработать чтоб  проверял и выводил простые числа от 2 до 13 например

Comment: Ну он же у тебя эхает все подряд - нужно строку завершать, хотя конечно это не обязательно, просто некрасиво.

Comment: докинул пример использования